# Multivariate transformation of random variables on Maple 17

Tags: probability, maple

I'm trying to workout a multivariate transformation of multiple random variables on Maple 17. I know how to work out for a single variable but couldn't get it to work for two variables. I'm trying to workout the following question.

$f(x,y) := \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      12xy(1-y) & 0< x< 1,0< y< 1  \\
      0 & elsewhere \\
\end{array} 
\right. \ $

Where the joint transformation of $(X,Y)$ is $Z=XY^2$ and $W=Y$

Comment: As far as I know, Maple has no support for multivariate distributions.